# Pasar una consulta a un datatable en un modal

Tags: javascript, datatable

Quiero visualizar un detalle de un datatable en una ventana modal desde un datatable de una página inicial

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo:

include("connection.php");
 $query ="SELECT * FROM caja ORDER BY id DESC"
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)

```
            <table id="caja" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Fecha</th>
                          <th>Compras</th>
                          <th>Ventas</th>
                          <th>Gastos</th>
                          <th>Total</th>
                          <th></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                     <?php  
                     $x=1;
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                      {  
                           echo '  
                           <tr>  
                                <td>'.$x++.'</td>
                                <td>20'.substr($row["codigo"],-8,2).' - '.substr($row["codigo"],-4,2).' - '.substr($row["codigo"],-2).'</td>    
                                <td>'.$row["compra"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["venta"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["gasto"].'</td>  
                                <td>'.$row["total"].'</td>  
                                <td> <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="caja('.$row['codigo'].') ">Ver Detalle</button> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" href="#"?id='.$row['codigo'].' >Modificar</a></td> 
                           </tr>  
                           ';  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <!-- /table -->

                $id=$_GET['.$row['codigo'];
                $querya ="SELECT * FROM cajadiaria where idcaja=".$id." "; 
                $resulta = mysqli_query($connect, $querya); 

                            <div id="productModal" class="modal fade">
                             <div class="modal-dialog">

                               <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                 <h4 class="modal-title">FLUJO DE CAJA DIARIA</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                 <table id="cajadetalle" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                          <th>Id</th>

                                          <th>Compras</th>
                                          <th>Ventas</th>
                                          <th>Gastos</th>


                                      </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                     <?php

                                     $a=1; 
                                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta))  
                                      {  
                                         ?>

                                           <tr> 

                                                <td><?php echo $a; $a++; ?></td>  

                                                <td> <?php echo $row['compras']; ?></td>  
                                                <td><?php echo $row['ventas']; ?></td>  
                                                <td><?php echo $row['gasto']; ?></td>  


                                           </tr>  
                                        <?php     
                                      }  
                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>

                                            <th>Total:</th>
                                             <th></th>
                                              <th></th>
                                               <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer" >



                                </div>
                               </div>
                              </form>
                             </div>
                            </div>
        </div> <!-- /panel-body -->
    </div> <!-- /panel -->      
</div> <!-- /col-md-12 -->
```

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#caja').DataTable();
 });
  
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#cajadetalle').DataTable();
 });

En conclusión solo quiero pasar una consulta filtrando el id desde otra consulta y q se muestre en mi modal.....

Comment: Te doy un consejo. No mezcles tus consultas con tus vistas; no solo es una mala práctica, también te dificulta increíblemente el mantenimiento de ese código; no respeta ningún pilar de la ingeniería de software como el [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Trabaja en capas, mínimo usa dos: Servicios (endpoints que devuelven datos a partir de consultas en forma de JSON) y Vistas (cliente). Desde el cliente, por medio de peticiones HTTP solicita los datos y muéstralos en el HTML

Comment: Otra opción, si no deseas usar AJAX, es usar una librería o framework web mvc, como Laravel o algo más pequeño como Phalcon. La idea es que no te acostumbres a escribir software de este modo porque luego te será difícil hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes llenar la tabla de esta manera

```
var table = $('#cajadetalle').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: 'archivo.php'
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'Id' },
    { data: 'Compras' },
    { data: 'Ventas' },
    { data: 'Gastos' }
  ]
});
```

El archivo php estaria respondiendo mandando la estructura que dataTable necesita para ser llenada.

```
// Tu consulta
$data = array();
if ($result) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

Comment: bien lo probare gracias por tomarte un tiempito en responder...